# Istio Pilot warning when adding multiple external services - "pilot_conflict_outbound_listener_tcp_over_current_tcp"

Tags: istio

I was trying to define multiple external services to route through Istio egress gateway using the following config.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: cnn
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: tls-cnn
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: google
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: tls-google
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
---
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    kind: Gateway
    metadata:
      name: istio-egressgateway
    spec:
      selector:
        istio: egressgateway
      servers:
      - port:
          number: 443
          name: tls-cnn
          protocol: TLS
        hosts:
        - edition.cnn.com
        tls:
          mode: PASSTHROUGH
      - port:
          number: 443
          name: tls-google
          protocol: TLS
        hosts:
        - www.google.com
        tls:
          mode: PASSTHROUGH
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: cnn
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  gateways:
  - mesh
  - istio-egressgateway
  tls:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - edition.cnn.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - edition.cnn.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: edition.cnn.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: google
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  gateways:
  - mesh
  - istio-egressgateway
  tls:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - www.google.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - www.google.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: www.google.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: disable-mtls-for-egressgateway
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
```

I can access external services but problem is that it creates an error in Istio pilot saying "pilot_conflict_outbound_listener_tcp_over_current_tcp".

Istio Versio - 1.4.4

Any suggestions to fix this warning would be awesome

Update
Based on https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16806#issuecomment-538718737, tried using different gateways as below and still getting same error in Pilot logs

```
"ProxyStatus": {
        "pilot_conflict_outbound_listener_tcp_over_current_tcp": {
            "0.0.0.0:443": {
                "proxy": "ratings-v1-5c46fc6f85-2f4zl.digital-services",
                "message": "Listener=0.0.0.0:443 AcceptedTCP=edition.cnn.com RejectedTCP=www.google.com TCPServices=1"
            }
        }
```

New config

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: cnn
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: tls-cnn
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: google
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: tls-google
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
---
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    kind: Gateway
    metadata:
      name: istio-egressgateway-cnn
    spec:
      selector:
        istio: egressgateway
      servers:
      - port:
          number: 443
          name: tls-cnn
          protocol: TLS
        hosts:
        - edition.cnn.com
        tls:
          mode: PASSTHROUGH
---
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    kind: Gateway
    metadata:
      name: istio-egressgateway-google
    spec:
      selector:
        istio: egressgateway
      servers:
      - port:
          number: 443
          name: tls-google
          protocol: TLS
        hosts:
        - www.google.com
        tls:
          mode: PASSTHROUGH
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: cnn
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  gateways:
  - mesh
  - istio-egressgateway-cnn
  tls:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - edition.cnn.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway-cnn
      port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - edition.cnn.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: edition.cnn.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: google
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  gateways:
  - mesh
  - istio-egressgateway-google
  tls:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - www.google.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway-google
      port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - www.google.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: www.google.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: disable-mtls-for-egressgateway
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
```

**UPDATE 2**
Tried using http protocol instead of tls as per @jt97 https://stackoverflow.com/users/11977760/jt97

It seems to be working but it throws same error when we add an Ingress gateway and virtual service (like one for kiali)

Config as follows

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: cnn
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https-cnn
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: google
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https-google
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
---
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    kind: Gateway
    metadata:
      name: istio-egressgateway-cnn
    spec:
      selector:
        istio: egressgateway
      servers:
      - port:
          number: 443
          name: https-cnn
          protocol: HTTP
        hosts:
        - edition.cnn.com
---
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    kind: Gateway
    metadata:
      name: istio-egressgateway-google
    spec:
      selector:
        istio: egressgateway
      servers:
      - port:
          number: 443
          name: https-google
          protocol: HTTP
        hosts:
        - www.google.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: cnn
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  gateways:
  - mesh
  - istio-egressgateway-cnn
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway-cnn
      port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: edition.cnn.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: google
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  gateways:
  - mesh
  - istio-egressgateway-google
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway-google
      port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: www.google.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: disable-mtls-for-egressgateway
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
```

Comment: Found a github issue which is still open and it might be connected to your problem, link [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16458). Could you tell me do you have global.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode set to ALLOW_ANY or REGISTER_ONLY? Can you tell me if there is any difference if you change protocol from TLS to HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: global.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode set to `ALLOW_ANY`. I will try using `https` protocol directly instead of `tls`

Comment: @jt97 Updated the description with http protocol instead of tls. But the same error occurred even when adding ingress gateway and virtual service.

Comment: Seems like it's istio bug and github is the place where you should ask about it, I found open istio issue [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19495) and another which might be related [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/17169). So it's rather question for istio devs on github how to deal with that. But since john howard said in first github issue, this error message isn't really accurate. So i think it's not really a issue itself, more like a warning.