# Egress gateway does't work correctly when adding multiple external services

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I was trying to define multiple external services(redis: AWS ElastiCache) to route through egress gateway. Two gateways were configured with reference to https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16806#issuecomment-538718737. I applied the following config, but it didn't work correctly and I could find error logs. It seemed that connecting to both of the destinations was forward to only one of them(random?)

Is this a bug or is there any solution?

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway-redis-1
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      name: redis
      number: 6379
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - "aaa.aaa.ng.0001.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: egress-redis-1
  namespace: test
spec:
  hosts:
  - aaa.aaa.ng.0001.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com
  ports:
  - name: egress-redis-1
    number: 6379
    protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: egress-redis-1
  namespace: test
spec:
  hosts:
  - aaa.aaa.ng.0001.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com
  gateways:
  - istio-egressgateway-redis-1
  - mesh
  tcp:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 6379
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        subset: egress-redis-1
        port:
          number: 6379
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway-redis-1
      port: 6379
    route:
    - destination:
        host: aaa.aaa.ng.0001.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com
        port:
          number: 6379
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: egress-redis-1
  namespace: test
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: egress-redis-1
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway-redis-2
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      name: redis
      number: 6379
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - "bbb.bbb.clustercfg.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: egress-redis-2
  namespace: test
spec:
  hosts:
  - bbb.bbb.clustercfg.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com
  ports:
  - name: egress-redis-2
    number: 6379
    protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: egress-redis-2
  namespace: test
spec:
  hosts:
  - bbb.bbb.clustercfg.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com
  gateways:
  - istio-egressgateway-redis-2
  - mesh
  tcp:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 6379
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        subset: egress-redis-2
        port:
          number: 6379
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway-redis-2
      port: 6379
    route:
    - destination:
        host: bbb.bbb.clustercfg.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com
        port:
          number: 6379
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: egress-redis-2
  namespace: test
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: egress-redis-2
```

Istio error logs:

```sh
2020-07-14T08:24:42.803875Z#011info#011ads#011Push Status: {
    "pilot_conflict_outbound_listener_tcp_over_current_tcp": {
        "0.0.0.0:6379": {
            "proxy": "member-11111-22222.test",
            "message": "Listener=0.0.0.0:6379 AcceptedTCP=aaa.aaa.clustercfg.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com RejectedTCP=bbb.bbb.ng.0001.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com TCPServices=1"
        }
    }
}
```

Version

```sh
Kubernetes: 1.18.5
Istio: 1.6.4
```

outboundTrafficPolicy

```sh
REGISTRY_ONLY
```

After updated port names of Gateway to unique, it still doesn't work.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway-redis-1
  namespace: qa2
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      name: egress-redis-1
      number: 6379
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - "aaa.aaa.ng.0001.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway-redis-2
  namespace: qa2
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      name: egress-redis-2
      number: 6379
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - "bbb.bbb.clustercfg.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: What you mean by `It seemed that connecting to both of the destinations was forward to only one of them`? aaa.aaa works, but bbb.bbb does not work? Could you show results from `curl -v` with both your hosts? Could you try to change name of your gateways from `redis` to unique names as mentioned [here](https://discuss.istio.io/t/attaching-multiple-gateways-to-istios-ingressgateway/5294/3)? Just to be sure it works, as this should be fixed in 1.1 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/12556)?

Comment: I mean that all of aaa and bbb was forwarded to aaa. Sometimes all was forwarded to bbb. After the port names were changed to unique names, still not worked. I updated question content.

Comment: I found [older case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309966/istio-pilot-warning-when-adding-multiple-external-services-pilot-conflict-out) which is similar but community member wanted to use TLS instead of TCP, error was the same. There was [open github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19495) about that and howardjohn mentioned there `This pilot_conflict_outbound_listener_tcp_over_current_tcp is no longer an issue in Istio 1.6`. As far as we can see there is still something wrong so I would recommend to open new github issue and mention above issue there.

Comment: Also take a look [there](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/17169).